# HTML-PHP Relative Path to Absolute Path

Tags: php, jquery, html, relative-path, absolute-path

Hi I am basically trying to fetch a page via php, get its html and change the html(to highlight some keywords) to a bit and display it as a overlay in my page(jquery).

```
//My php page data.php
<?php
$html=  file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
echo $html;
?>

//My jquery ajax request to data.php from page main.html
function test()
{  

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'data.php',
            data: 'url=http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=338',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) 
            {           
                 $("#overlay").append(result);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

As you can see, since the webpage uses relative URL, I am having issues displaying it in a overlay. I tried searching for a way to convert relative to absolute but did not find anything useful. Can you guys please point me in the right way?

Comment: Why do you think a relative URL affects the ability to show the ajax result in a div? It doesnt make sense.

Comment: Say if a image tag has a relative source, since I only take out the html and display it in my webpage, the image wont get displayed. That is why I want to convert relative to absolute,so I can get that image.

Comment: Ah! So what you **really** wants is to change the paths in the scraped HTML to absolute paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ilke @charlietfl's solution. However, somehow I think it gives more sense to manipulate the scraped content serverside *before* passing it to the client. You can do that by using [**DomDocument**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

The following code converts **all** `<img>` `src` relative paths to absolute paths before echoing the result. Use the same approch for the `<a>` tags `href` attributes and so on,

```php
error_reporting(0); //suppress DOM errors
$basePath='http://www.developphp.com/'; //use parse_url to get the basepath dynamically
$content=file_get_contents('http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=338');
$dom=new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $src=$image->attributes->getNamedItem("src")->value;
    if (strpos($basePath, $src)<=0) {
        $image->attributes->getNamedItem("src")->value=$basePath.$src;
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: server side certainly will work, one advantage in client side is might be easier to debug string tests by outputting to console without needing something like firephp to do it

Comment: Hey @charlietfl, I dont know firephp. I follow you, but I usually develop PHP ajaxscripts by calling them directly and output all errors along temporary results. When the script works, I call it by javascript ajax, and then it can go into production. You dont have to call the scripts by javascript to debug them.

Comment: understood...matter of preference is what it really boils down to. For me I can debug this thing faster in JS using php as nothing but a proxy to get the content

Comment: I like console.log etc too. Maybe I am "spoiled" but having a setup of $this->debug, $this->debugFile in my baseclass, so I can follow the produced SQL, for example, all outputs, results and so on very easy. So I really not need a thirdparty profiler. I inherit from a baseclass and run. A thing you forget, console.log messes up in IE when you are not in developermode, it actually produces an error. So either way, there is thing to consider. Regards ..

Comment: basically am more JS oriented, you're obviously more backend. I never use console.log in development code without a wrapper for it ...basically `if( window.console)`. Since I do do tons of ajax...I use firephp quite a bit also....logs to console by inserting data in headers sent from server

Comment: Using `if (!window.console) console = { log: function(){} };` too :) Will look for firephp, never heard about it before (I think)

Answer (score 2):

Can start here

```
function test(){  
    var domain='http://www.developphp.com/', path= 'view_lesson.php?v=338';
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'data.php',
            data: { url: domain + path},
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) 
            {      
               var $html=updatePaths( $(result) );

                 $("#overlay").append($html);

            }
        });

}

function updatePaths( $html, domain){
  /* loop over all images and adjust src*/
  $html.find('img').attr(src,function(i, src){
    if(src.indexOf(domain) ==-1){
      src= domain+src
    }
    return src;
  })
  /* return updated jQuery object*/
  return $html;

}
```

This will only work for simplest case where remote site isn't using a variation of the domain you use like not using `www` and you do. Also won't work if image paths are set usng `../` to move up a directory.

You would have to create a far more robust set of tests to manipulate the final path you use correctly.

My intent was to show you how to manage situation

Answer (score 0):

With all your help, I did something like this,

Instead of trying to replace the relative by absolute path, I appended the base url html tag to the scrapped content.

```
<?php
include 'URL2.php';
error_reporting(0); //suppress DOM errors
$content=file_get_contents($_GET['fullURL']);  //http://somewebsite.com/page1.html
$url = new Net_URL2($_GET['fullURL']);
$baseURL= $url->host; //http://somewebsite.com
if(strpos($baseURL,'http://')<0)
{
    $baseURL='http://'.$baseURL;
}
$dom=new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$head = $dom->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0);
$base = $dom->createElement('base');
$base->setAttribute('href',$_GET['baseURL']);

if ($head->hasChildNodes()) {
    $head->insertBefore($base,$head->firstChild);
} else {
    $head->appendChild($base);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```